# WPF binding checked event in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm new to MVVM pattern, I must intercept the checked/unchecked operation inside a the following view

**SendMessageView.xaml**

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
         <CheckBox Checked="Specialita_Checked" 
                Unchecked="Specialita_Unchecked"
                Content="{Binding Path=Item.Name}"
                IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, 
                            Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
      </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

**SendMessageView.xaml.cs**

```
private void Specialita_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var aSendMessageViewModel = (SendMessageViewModel)this.DataContext;
   if (aSendMessageViewModel != null)
   {
      var aCheckBox = (CheckBox)sender;
      aSendMessageViewModel.AddSpecialita(aCheckBox.Content.ToString());
   }
}
```

A file called `aSendMessageViewModel.cs` is call inside a `SendMessageView.xaml.cs` and this is not correct.
Help me in correctly using MVVM pattern.

Comment: Have you ever heard about indentation ?

Comment: Kek, perhaps you could edit the code and make it prettier. (If you have enough rep that is)

Comment: yes ,but how is possible ident the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll in your project and reference it at the top of your xaml (xmlns:i="...")

Then you can do:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel>
         <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Item.Name}"
                IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, 
                            Path=IsSelected,Mode=TwoWay}">
             <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.OnCheckedCommand, ElementName=myCtrl}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
             </i:Interaction.Triggers>
         </CheckBox>
      </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And use a command named OnCheckedCommand in your ViewModel to handle it.

Comment: ok.. but how can i pass the parameter? The parameter to pass is Item.Name

Comment: Did not work. I used http://www.jarloo.com/how-to-create-a-checkedlistbox-in-wpf/ and subscribed to PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write

```
aSendMessageViewModel.AddSpecialita(aCheckBox.Content.ToString());
```

in the IsSelected setter of your ListBoxItem datacontext ?

**EDIT**

What will happen when you check your check box is your SelectedItem of your listBox will change (due to IsSelected on ListViewItem).
Then you could do something in the setter of the SlectedItem of DataContext of your listBox

```
public MyObject SelectedItem 
{
   get { return _selItem; }
   set
   {
      if(_selItem != value)
      {
          if(_selItem != null)
             _selItem.OnUncheck();
          _selItem = value;
          _selItem.OnCheck();
          NotifyPropertyChange("SelectedItem"); 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I want to bind the checked and unchecked operation from SendMessageView.xaml directly to aSendMessageViewModel.cs without call aSendMessageViewModel inside a SendMessageView.xaml.cs

Comment: mm..ok ok... i think can i use dependency property for this... ok ... thanks for your response.

Comment: surely you don't understand the MVVM pattern either. Don't ever put anything in setters/getters aside from raising propertychanged and actually getting/settings values.

Comment: ever ? Better creating a complex 4 unreadable XAML lines + a command to call something that NEED to be called ? Discutable. It may depend on what is to be written in this command. Actually this would be even better if that was in the model setter...

Comment: It is not discutable, if you put logic in getters/setters, it will execute when you map objects, on deserialization... and it's only the entrance to hell, you will then enjoy an infinite number of levels of doom and despair. Just don't.

Comment: @Kek if you want a more thourough answer on that point, please set up a question and I'll try to give an exhaustive answer.

Comment: I don't... I know your concerns. If they are quite right, the answer you gave has exactly the same problems... (saying "exactly", I mean it). Problem is deeper than saying "never kill you neighbour" and ask an assassin to do so :)